# Returning string from function is not giving proper output

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to make a function which will receive a `char *` from the user and will print it.

It turns my value to something weird when I'm printing it.

```
**//input method**

char* readContactName(){
    char tmp[20];
    do{
    printf("What is your contact name?: (max %d chars) ", MAX_LENGH);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s", &tmp);
    } while (!strcmp(tmp, ""));

    return tmp;
}

void readContact (Contact* contact) 
{

    char* tmp;

    tmp = readContactName();
    updateContactName(contact, tmp);
}

**//when entering this function the string is correct**
void updateContactName(Contact* contact, char str[MAX_LENGH])
{
    printf("contact name is %s\n",&str);  --> prints rubish
}
```

What did I miss here?

Comment: You cannot return pointers to local variables in C. The compiler lets you do this, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, `char tmp[20];` is local to the function `readContactName()`. Once the function finishes execution, there is no existence of `tmp`. So, the address-of-`tmp` also becomes invalid.

So, after `return`ing, in the caller, if you try to use the `return`ed pointer, (*as you're doing in `updateContactName(contact, tmp);()`*) it will invoke [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

FWIW, `fflush(stdin);` is also UB. `fflush()` is only defined for output streams.

Solution:

- Define `tmp` as to be a pointer.
- Allocate memory dynamically (using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) or family).
- Once you're done using the allocated memory, you need to [`free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free) it also.

Comment: thanks... it really helped!

Comment: Do you have a template already in place for this? ;-)

Comment: I was referring to the answer itself ... :-)